# How to install TClientSocket and TServerSocket for multi-platform?

Tags: c++, c++builder, multiplatform

In C++Builder, how can I install `TClientSocket` and `TServerSocket` for use in a multi-platform app?  Currently I use them in a VCL-only project.

Comment: im asking: how can i install TClientSocket adn TServerSocket? i need to use it for multiplatform app, now i had those components in VLC proj only

Comment: Unfortunately, Stack Overflow is a site for English only questions and answers, and therefore unless translated this question isn't suitable. Stack Overflow is available in other languages, you could try [Portugal SO](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/), [Spanish SO](http://es.stackoverflow.com/) or uh, [Russian maybe?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: If you are able to translate your question into English, feel free to [edit your question!](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35427784/edit)

Answer (score 4):

> How can I install TClientSocket and TServerSocket?

This is covered in Embarcadero's documentation:

[Installing Socket Components](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Installing_Socket_Components)

> The socket components are not installed by default. To use the socket components, you must install the **dclsockets<.bpl>** package.
>
> To install the socket components:
>   1. Select Component > Install Packages.
>   2. In the Install Packages dialog box, click Add.
>   3. In the Add Design Package dialog, browse to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\bin`.
>   4. Select dclsockets230.bpl, and click Open.
>   5. Click OK to dismiss Install Packages dialog.
>   6. The socket components (TClientSocket and TServerSocket) are listed in the Internet category of the Tool Palette.
>
> Note: These steps are one-time installation instructions. The socket components should be available for all future projects.

That being said...

> I need to use it for multiplatform app, now I had those components in VCL project only.

`TClientSocket` and `TServerSocket` are NOT multi-platform components.  They are intimately tied to Microsoft's WinSock library on Windows, and only work in VCL projects, not FMX projects.  For multi-platform socket work, you can use [Indy](http://www.indyproject.org) instead, which is pre-installed in RADStudio, or you can install an [up-to-date version](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.aspx) manually.